# Concerning terminal pagers

Tags: windows, unix, ms-dos

```
more < doc.txt
```

I understand that the above command will display the contents of the `doc.txt` file until it fills up the screen. I can, then, go down one line at a time with the arrow keys or keep going page by page. I'm looking for a way to display the contents of the file one line at a time.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: @Steven doesn't matter. can you really not answer for all 3, it's not hard. And if you don't know then just answer for the ones you know about. He tagged it with 3 different operating systems. So it's not your fault if he changes his mind.  You could just answer it and say that's what the question originally asked and you've answered it. That's if he were to change his min,  But he is welcome to ask about all 3.  If you're really not able to answer for all 3, or even 2, or even 1, then check my answer.

Comment: Most people will not know the meaning of “from the get-go”, I think from consulting with a teenager that it means “from the start”.

Comment: @richard. i'm surprised you've never heard of that phrase; it's a fairly old and widely-used idiom. :)

Comment: -1 Do not use slang in questions. And even if you did mean "from the beginning" you should clarify what you mean. I suppose re-reading it, that you might mean display one line then wait for a key to be pushed, then display another line. Of course, the 'more' command operates from the beginning of the file.`type` also shows a file "from the get go"/beginning, it just shows the whole file no need for any key to be pushed,which kind of sounds speedy fitting your slang.So even without the slang u still should clarify.U r supposedly writing a technical question, so use technical precise language

Comment: @barlop it's not slang; it's an idiom used just as often in writing as in speech. i am not versed in jargon, so it would be confusing if we used it. slang and idioms are much more widely understood than jargon. jargon should only be used in a discussion if all parties involved have a good understanding of the subject at hand, as in a discussion between two work colleagues. this is a site where strangers ask each other questions—hardly the place for jargon. you misread my question, though it was written clearly. you overlooked my stating i was "clueless." take responsibility for your mistakes.

Comment: You are not clueless, you used the term "terminal pager" which is a technical term that is little known, it only gets 6000 results in google, the first result wikipedia, the second result cisco, .  That is 6* less common than the technical phrase for NAPT "network address port translation".which gets 36000 results.  I am all for America, but some Americanisms are so silly they'll never leave America and only a portion of americans will ever use them. We have the word "beginning", use it rather than baby talk "get go",  and then it's clearer because it opens the question beginning of what.

Comment: You are showing eloquence now, but you still have not clarified, beginning of what. Every program starts from the beginning of the file. If you're really not saying anything at all by saying "from the beginning", then it's as pointless as saying the command already reads from the beginning of the file, and you want it to read to the end of the file. It's absurd to say, because the command already goes to the end of the file.

Comment: Please use capitals, for "I" and at the start of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer for Cmd

```
C:\blah>for /f "delims==" %f in (a.txt) do @echo %f&&pause<ENTER>
a sdf
Press any key to continue . . .
b sdf
Press any key to continue . . .
c sdf
Press any key to continue . . .
```

You could write a bat file

```
C:\blah>type wolly.bat
@for /f "delims==" %%f in (%1) do @echo %%f&&pause
C:\blah>
```

And then you would type

```
C:\blah>wolly a.txt
a sdf
Press any key to continue . . .
b sdf
Press any key to continue . . .
c sdf
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\blah>
```